# Unique Conditional Formatting Using Multiple Columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I currently have the following excel worksheet layout:

```
ColumnA | ColumnB | ColumnC     ColumnF | ColumnG | ColumnH 
--------|---------|---------    --------|---------|---------
123     | 456     | 456         123     | 456     | 456       
--------|---------|---------    --------|---------|---------
456     | 947     | 1331        456     | 0511    | 1331       
--------|---------|---------    --------|---------|---------
1121    | 1255    | 512         1121    | 1255    | 512
```

What I need to be able to do is compare data and format unique rows against `Columns A - C` with `Columns F - H`.

The end result would be the second row `ColumnF-H` being formatted as unique as the `ColumnG` (0511) doesn't match `ColumnB` (947)

The only way I have managed this so far is concatenating all the values into a single cell for each 3 column data set and then compare against that, however this no longer works as I need it to with the most recent data additions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this rule applied to columns `F:H`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(1*($F1:$H1<>$A1:$C1))>0
```

The `SUMPRODUCT` allows you to compare F to A, G to B, and H to C with one comparison rather than three. That said, you could just as well use `OR` in your rule to the same effect since you're only comparing three values.

```
=OR($F1<>$A1,$G1<>$B1,$H1<>$C1)
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thank you very much :)